# Resize textarea after deleting text

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you write text, a `textarea` increases in size, but when you delete this text then nothing happens. Is it possible to dynamically decrease the height of a `textarea` if you are deleting text?

```js
$('textarea').on('input', function() {
  var scrollHeight = parseInt($(this).prop('scrollHeight'));
  $(this).height(scrollHeight);
});
```

```css
.OuterDiv
{
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
  bottom:0;
}
.text
{
  resize:none;
  width:198px;
  height:45px;
  max-height:145px;
  background-color:rgba(90,90,180,1);
  font-size:16px;
  font-family:Arial;
  overflow-y:auto;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="OuterDiv">
  <textarea class="text" placeholder="Write some text..."></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the `height` style instead of the property, and use an initial height so as to always start at `45px`.

```js
$('textarea').on('input', function() {
    $(this).css('height', "45px");
    $(this).css('height', this.scrollHeight+"px");
});
```

```css
.OuterDiv
{
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
  bottom:0;
  }
.text
{
  resize:none;
  width:198px;
  height:45px;
  max-height:145px;
  background-color:rgba(90,90,180,1);
  font-size:16px;
  font-family:Arial;
  overflow-y:auto;
  padding:0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="OuterDiv">
  <textarea class="text" placeholder="Write some text..."></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a div with `contentEditable` instead it will auto-resize depending on the contentno need for any script :

```css
.OuterDiv
{
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
  bottom:0;
}
.text
{
  resize:none;
  width:198px;
  min-height:45px;
  height:auto;
  max-height:145px;
  background-color:rgba(90,90,180,1);
  font-size:16px;
  font-family:Arial;
  overflow-y:auto;
  padding:0;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before{
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block; /* For Firefox */
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="OuterDiv">
  <div class="text" contentEditable="true" placeholder="Write some text..."></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It _works_ but I wouldn't recommend the `contentEditable` option. It allows to put not only text, but also HTML code with scripts etc. Without proper sanitization it's very dangerous. It also keeps styling from copied content so you also need to write a lot of CSS to reset all to fit your styleguide (unless you're parsing it as simple text).

Comment: If you didn't recommend it doesn't mean you've to downvote it, you could attach your comment to the answer as a note so it will be a plus instead of downvoting a _working_ sample.